# Get valid URL from string using Bash script

Tags: xml, bash, shell

I am parsing an xml file using xmllint. Theres an element `description` in each `<item>`  with CDATA text inside from which I would like to extract the title (text until forst `<br />`) and the URL of a specific domain (desiredURL.com). I am not a pro in regeular expression and the use of `awk` and `sed`. Is there a way to parse the data in the `description` element using xmllint again or what would be an appropriate approach? I want to iterate over all the `<item>` and print the title and the url of the domain desiredURL.com

```
#!/bin/bash
ITEMS=`echo "cat  //item/description/text()" | xmllint --shell  file.xml  | egrep '^\w'`
#iterate over items and print title and desiredURL


file.xml:

<item>
    <description><![CDATA[A title for the URLs<br /><br />

    http://www.foobar.com/foo/bar
    <br />http://bar.com/foo
    <br />http://myurl.com/foo
    <br />http://desiredURL.com/files/ddd
    <br />http://asdasd.com/onefile/g.html
    <br />http://second.com/link
    <br />]]></description> 



    </item>
<description> ...</description>
    <item>
</item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### XMLlint

There is an `--xpath` option you can use to pass an `XPath`.

### Extracting URL

Assuming your URLs are **not followed** by anything on each line, you can use `grep` with :

- `-P flag`: Perl regular expression (PCRE) ;
- `-o flag`: only print the  matched (non-empty) parts.

### Command

```
xmllint --xpath '//item/description' /tmp/so.xml | grep -Po 'http:.*'
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to get all <item> elements into an array and iterate over the arrays? then, for each array, iterate over the lines of the <description> element?

Comment: @tzippy Yes it possible. However you shoudl valid this answer, and ask another question as it's a different problem.

Comment: @Eduard Lopez: I did, thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495885/bash-script-get-xml-elements-into-array-using-xmllint