# Bash script: Get XML elements into array using xmllint

Tags: xml, bash, shell

This is a follow up question to  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489279/get-valid-url-from-string-using-bash-script/20490304).

I want to end up with an array, containing all the `<description>` elements of the xml.

```
array[0] = "<![CDATA[A title for .... <br />]]>"
array[1] = "<![CDATA[A title for .... <br />]]>"
```

...

```
file.xml:

<item>
    <description><![CDATA[A title for the URLs<br /><br />

    http://www.foobar.com/foo/bar
    <br />http://bar.com/foo
    <br />http://myurl.com/foo
    <br />http://desiredURL.com/files/ddd
    <br />http://asdasd.com/onefile/g.html
    <br />http://second.com/link
    <br />]]></description> 


</item>
    </item>
<description> ...</description>
    <item>
```

Comment: why do you want to store them in an array ?

Comment: I want to extract values from each array object. What better solution thatn an array would you suggest? What would be an Xpath expression for that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A `Bash` solution could be

```
let itemsCount=$(xmllint --xpath 'count(//item/description)' /tmp/so.xml)
declare -a description=( )

for (( i=1; i <= $itemsCount; i++ )); do 
    description[$i]="$(xmllint --xpath '//item['$i']/description' /tmp/so.xml)"
done

echo ${description[@]}
```

### Disclaimer

Consider that `bash` may not be the right tool. XSLT/XPath could give you direct access to the content of the `description` element as describe in previous answer. For instance:

```
xmllint --xpath '//item/description/text()' /tmp/so.xml
```

Return every `<description>` content

Comment: Thank you! The thing is that, what you described in your disclaimer, returns all the content of the description elements in one string. That's not too useful for further processing.

Comment: code before disclaimer should do what you ask. Disclaimer is here to only if you don't care/need the element `description` that serve as source

Comment: I think in the bash solution it should be "smallerThanOrEqualTo" <= for (( i=1; i <= $itemsCount; i++ )); do